# Is there a way to reset the password for a list of Active Directory users en-mass?

Tags: active-directory, password, batch, reset, bulk

I have a list of user accounts that need their password reset to a default password (also users will be required to change the password at first login). Is there a way to reset the password for a list of Active Directory users en-mass? I'd rather not use any third party software. Can I do this in dsa.exe? Or can this be done with a power-shell script? I've seen some examples that reset the passwords for all users in an OU but this will not work for me. I need to reset the passwords for only 50 of 300 users in the same OU.

Answer (score 3):

If all accounts are to be reset to the same password, you could probably do something like this:

```
for /f %%u in (users.txt) do @net user %%u PASS /logonpasswordchg:yes /domain
```

Answer (score 3):

[Yup](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/08/17/how-to-change-a-user-s-active-directory-password-with-powershell.aspx).

You can loop and read in the names of the accounts you need to reset from a `.csv` of the usernames, which you hopefully already have in a list somewhere.

[If you have the AD module for PowerShell, it's even easier](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winserverpowershell/thread/b0c2e59f-522e-40a3-ab12-3a95d045d6a8) (you can also read in a `.csv` of the usernames with this method, instead of using a filter).

> First, you need to import ActiveDirectory Module
>
> *Import-Module ActiveDirectory*
>
> Second, generate a SecureString which contains the password.
>
> *$securePwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "P@ssw0rd!" -Force
>   -AsPlainText*
>
> Third, find the Active Directory users ,and use Set-ADAccountPassword for resetng the password.
>
> *Get-ADUser -Filter {Name -like "Test*"} | Set-ADAccountPassword -NewPassword $securePwd*
>
> Also, you can review following link for more details about the Active Directory cmdlets.
>
> Active Directory Cmdlets in Windows PowerShell
>
> http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617195.aspx

Answer (score 3):

This question is already been discussed at the community before. Please refer to this link

[How do I bulk reset passwords for all users in an OU?](https://serverfault.com/questions/207115/how-do-i-bulk-reset-passwords-for-all-users-in-an-ou)

and you can go for this link also Mass password change at active directory

http://blog.scottlowe.org/2005/12/08/mass-password-changes-in-active-directory/

ELse go for a freeware tool such as Lepide Active Directory Self service. It will allow you to change the password for limitation up to 50 users.

Comment: The question specifically states that the users are not all in the same OU. How does the other question you linked relate to this one, then?