# Active Directory - set passwords for an entire group

Tags: active-directory, password, bulk

I have an active directory server where users are divided in various security groups, and I've been trying to find a way to reset passwords for all of them at once.

So first I thought I could just use dsquery. The command

```
dsquery group -name "<group>" -uc | dsget group -members -uc
```

got me the strings for all of the users. This is nice and all, but when I piped the output to a file cmd always saved it as a ANSI file no matter the codepage settings etc. This corrupted the output and I couldn't load it back to loop through it, and you can't easily store the output of a piped programs to a variable in batch, so that was out of the window.

dsquery on powershell simply refused to work. With DN or not, it always said that "directory object couldn't be found". ([As seen here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrc9I.jpg)).

Same with `Get-ADUser` and `Get-ADGroup` etc. commands from the powershell's AD Module ([like the ones described here](https://serverfault.com/a/207176/375262)). They either timed out or they simply exited without returning anything. No error, no success message, nothing. Of course passwords remain unchanged.

So the question is: how do I change passwords for an entire group at once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like `Get-AdGroupMember -Identity 'GroupName' -Recursive` should get you the list of users; if the list looks right, then `Get-AdGroupMember -Identity 'GroupName' -Recursive | Set-AdAccountPassword -Reset -NewPassword 'SomePassword'`  should change them all.